# How does replenishing Alchemy items like potions work?

Tags: the-witcher-3

From what I have learned so far, I only need to create a potion once and then it'll be automatically refilled from strong alcohol when I meditate. But there are a few details I'm not sure about.

- How much alcohol is used up, one per item or one per meditation?
- Are bombs and oils filled up the same way?
- Does it matter which potions or bombs are equipped at the time of meditation?

Answer (score 9):

Testing this myself (after reading your other question on this subject), and finding some more information on the internet, I can conclude that:

- Regardless of the amount of supplies that are refilled **one** alcoholic item is used
- Bombs are also replenished
- It appears that oils do not need to be replenished
- All supplies, equipped or in the inventory, will be replenished the same

You can read more about this and other inventory mechanics in [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/36lag2/guide_to_inventory_management_or_so_many_herbs_so/). I have confirmed the part about replenishing supplies myself by testing in-game.

Comment: Oils don't seem to be used up, I just tried it quickly and they're still in the inventory after applying. So it might be that they don't need to be replenished.